# Visualisation of neural network, How to change the line width based on the weights?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to make a visualisation of a neural network and the line weight and the colour of the line between the nodes need to correspond to the values of the weights, (positive -> red , negative -> blue and the thickness of the line should change based on the absolute value) very similar to the [NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html) illustration below.

[image]

I have been able to create the neural network using and show the weights value, shown in the code and result image below. How can I change the code to be to get the plot as above.

```
## Gist originally developed by @craffel and improved by @ljhuang2017

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
coefs_ = w
def draw_neural_net(ax, left, right, bottom, top, layer_sizes, coefs_):
    '''
    Draw a neural network cartoon using matplotilb.
    
    :usage:
        >>> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
        >>> draw_neural_net(fig.gca(), .1, .9, .1, .9, [4, 7, 2])
    
    :parameters:
        - ax : matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot
            The axes on which to plot the cartoon (get e.g. by plt.gca())
        - left : float
            The center of the leftmost node(s) will be placed here
        - right : float
            The center of the rightmost node(s) will be placed here
        - bottom : float
            The center of the bottommost node(s) will be placed here
        - top : float
            The center of the topmost node(s) will be placed here
        - layer_sizes : list of int
            List of layer sizes, including input and output dimensionality
    '''
    n_layers = len(layer_sizes)
    v_spacing = (top - bottom)/float(max(layer_sizes))
    h_spacing = (right - left)/float(len(layer_sizes) - 1)
    
    # Input-Arrows
    layer_top_0 = v_spacing*(layer_sizes[0] - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
    for m in range(layer_sizes[0]):
        plt.arrow(left-0.15, layer_top_0 - m*v_spacing, 0.12, 0,  lw =0.05, head_width=0.01, head_length=0.02)
    
    # Nodes
    for n, layer_size in enumerate(layer_sizes):
        layer_top = v_spacing*(layer_size - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
        for m in range(layer_size):
            circle = plt.Circle((n*h_spacing + left, layer_top - m*v_spacing), v_spacing/8.,
                                color='w', ec='k', zorder=4)
            if n == 0:
                plt.text(left-0.125, layer_top - m*v_spacing, r'$X_{'+str(m+1)+'}$', fontsize=15)
            elif (n_layers == 3) & (n == 1):
                plt.text(n*h_spacing + left+0.00, layer_top - m*v_spacing+ (v_spacing/8.+0.01*v_spacing), r'$H_{'+str(m+1)+'}$', fontsize=15)
            elif n == n_layers -1:
                plt.text(n*h_spacing + left+0.10, layer_top - m*v_spacing, r'$y_{'+str(m+1)+'}$', fontsize=15)
            ax.add_artist(circle)

    # Edges between nodes
    for n, (layer_size_a, layer_size_b) in enumerate(zip(layer_sizes[:-1], layer_sizes[1:])):
        layer_top_a = v_spacing*(layer_size_a - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
        layer_top_b = v_spacing*(layer_size_b - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
        for m in range(layer_size_a):
            for o in range(layer_size_b):
                line = plt.Line2D([n*h_spacing + left, (n + 1)*h_spacing + left],
                                  [layer_top_a - m*v_spacing, layer_top_b - o*v_spacing], c='k')
                ax.add_artist(line)
                xm = (n*h_spacing + left)
                xo = ((n + 1)*h_spacing + left)
                ym = (layer_top_a - m*v_spacing)
                yo = (layer_top_b - o*v_spacing)
                rot_mo_rad = np.arctan((yo-ym)/(xo-xm))
                rot_mo_deg = rot_mo_rad*180./np.pi
                xm1 = xm + (v_spacing/8.+0.05)*np.cos(rot_mo_rad)
                if n == 0:
                    if yo > ym:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.12)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                    else:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.05)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                else:
                    if yo > ym:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.12)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                    else:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.04)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                plt.text( xm1, ym1,\
                         str(round(coefs_[n][m, o],4)),\
                         rotation = rot_mo_deg, \
                         fontsize = 10)
               
    # Output-Arrows
    layer_top_0 = v_spacing*(layer_sizes[-1] - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
    for m in range(layer_sizes[-1]):
        plt.arrow(right+0.011, layer_top_0 - m*v_spacing, 0.16*h_spacing, 0,  lw =0.05, head_width=0.01, head_length=0.02)
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.axis('off')

# layer_sizes = [7] + [10] + [7]
layer_sizes = nodes
draw_neural_net(ax, .1, .9, .1, .9, layer_sizes, coefs_)
fig.savefig('nn_digaram.png')
```

[image]

The values of coefs_ are

```
array([matrix([[-0.94539221,  4.71558222,  1.18114055, -0.0247317 ,  0.65897569,
         -4.56814996, -3.35490889,  0.1859133 ,  0.07424753,  6.90725199],
        [-2.48287521,  3.14839658,  0.44249679, -0.32001095, -1.14217304,
         -1.9226931 , -2.4374025 ,  2.35347059, -0.54031149,  3.9080797 ],
        [ 0.15713579, -0.10550088,  1.88657889,  1.69982016, -0.57003659,
          0.23898249,  0.53788204,  0.58590049,  3.56283575, -1.52514785],
        [ 2.78640583,  2.69520817,  2.91659772,  0.83917307,  2.63572781,
          2.38591315,  1.16198163,  1.24653089,  1.43679067,  0.52219298],
        [ 0.56640031,  1.56162596,  3.53929899, -4.92257699,  3.10732374,
         -1.71019921, -1.45060365, -1.9656212 , -2.54415882,  0.57261768],
        [-1.32074064,  0.94831387,  0.47141262, -3.64962347,  3.39212857,
          0.77377745,  1.04295819,  7.11011713,  1.18975941,  1.59917691],
        [ 0.977984  ,  1.07923358, -2.81972891,  4.65242696, -3.10353591,
         -0.68438475, -1.39959398, -1.22330595,  0.45223289,  0.65884348]]),
       matrix([[-0.49489946,  0.17994493, -0.03041135, -1.2021098 ,  2.00356709,
          2.19315657, -2.39778753],
        [ 0.00898019, -0.01341118, -1.42407278, -0.98645785, -1.23737296,
         -1.31009782,  0.32579397],
        [ 1.01009537, -0.08545276,  0.28988038,  3.46345191, -0.09588307,
          0.90830877, -2.08828012],
        [-4.97097194,  0.01332595,  0.58301252,  2.10843412,  0.37481177,
         -1.83738501,  2.92358809],
        [ 3.93275315, -0.02436187,  0.51174384, -2.15054043, -0.9096572 ,
         -3.14182279,  2.7819789 ],
        [ 0.04236115,  0.83878036,  0.38800743,  1.83881625,  0.95167318,
          0.46700375,  1.17837088],
        [ 0.86639556,  1.11735707,  0.76364426,  1.05078341,  0.7146457 ,
          1.16666294,  0.75577211],
        [ 2.31029687,  5.89363035, -6.65521314,  0.60303478, -0.87160711,
         -1.47199575, -2.88012028],
        [-0.12512919,  2.20846339,  6.21649468, -3.41157653, -1.29878851,
          0.06757862, -2.03271134],
        [ 0.59767784, -0.00900227, -1.79903724, -1.84302839, -1.68108604,
         -1.36057165, -0.46816008]])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the coefficients `coefs_ = w` so we can run the code for a test?

Comment: @Andrea Thanks a lot for your reply. I edited the original question and added the values for coefs_.  Hope this format is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on how you want to normalize your weights. For example, if you want each layer of the network to be normalized you can do something that looks like this:

```
normed_coef = np.array([(c / np.max(np.abs(c)) + 1) /2 for c in coefs_])
```

This way you can use a matplotlib colormap like this:

```
import matplotlib
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('RdBu_r')

c=cmap(normed_coef[n][m, o])
```

---

Putting all together:

```
## Gist originally developed by @craffel and improved by @ljhuang2017

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('RdBu_r')


coefs_ = np.array([np.matrix([[-0.94539221,  4.71558222,  1.18114055, -0.0247317 ,  0.65897569,
         -4.56814996, -3.35490889,  0.1859133 ,  0.07424753,  6.90725199],
        [-2.48287521,  3.14839658,  0.44249679, -0.32001095, -1.14217304,
         -1.9226931 , -2.4374025 ,  2.35347059, -0.54031149,  3.9080797 ],
        [ 0.15713579, -0.10550088,  1.88657889,  1.69982016, -0.57003659,
          0.23898249,  0.53788204,  0.58590049,  3.56283575, -1.52514785],
        [ 2.78640583,  2.69520817,  2.91659772,  0.83917307,  2.63572781,
          2.38591315,  1.16198163,  1.24653089,  1.43679067,  0.52219298],
        [ 0.56640031,  1.56162596,  3.53929899, -4.92257699,  3.10732374,
         -1.71019921, -1.45060365, -1.9656212 , -2.54415882,  0.57261768],
        [-1.32074064,  0.94831387,  0.47141262, -3.64962347,  3.39212857,
          0.77377745,  1.04295819,  7.11011713,  1.18975941,  1.59917691],
        [ 0.977984  ,  1.07923358, -2.81972891,  4.65242696, -3.10353591,
         -0.68438475, -1.39959398, -1.22330595,  0.45223289,  0.65884348]]),
       np.matrix([[-0.49489946,  0.17994493, -0.03041135, -1.2021098 ,  2.00356709,
          2.19315657, -2.39778753],
        [ 0.00898019, -0.01341118, -1.42407278, -0.98645785, -1.23737296,
         -1.31009782,  0.32579397],
        [ 1.01009537, -0.08545276,  0.28988038,  3.46345191, -0.09588307,
          0.90830877, -2.08828012],
        [-4.97097194,  0.01332595,  0.58301252,  2.10843412,  0.37481177,
         -1.83738501,  2.92358809],
        [ 3.93275315, -0.02436187,  0.51174384, -2.15054043, -0.9096572 ,
         -3.14182279,  2.7819789 ],
        [ 0.04236115,  0.83878036,  0.38800743,  1.83881625,  0.95167318,
          0.46700375,  1.17837088],
        [ 0.86639556,  1.11735707,  0.76364426,  1.05078341,  0.7146457 ,
          1.16666294,  0.75577211],
        [ 2.31029687,  5.89363035, -6.65521314,  0.60303478, -0.87160711,
         -1.47199575, -2.88012028],
        [-0.12512919,  2.20846339,  6.21649468, -3.41157653, -1.29878851,
          0.06757862, -2.03271134],
        [ 0.59767784, -0.00900227, -1.79903724, -1.84302839, -1.68108604,
         -1.36057165, -0.46816008]])], dtype=object)

def draw_neural_net(ax, left, right, bottom, top, layer_sizes, coefs_):
    '''
    Draw a neural network cartoon using matplotilb.
    
    :usage:
        >>> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
        >>> draw_neural_net(fig.gca(), .1, .9, .1, .9, [4, 7, 2])
    
    :parameters:
        - ax : matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot
            The axes on which to plot the cartoon (get e.g. by plt.gca())
        - left : float
            The center of the leftmost node(s) will be placed here
        - right : float
            The center of the rightmost node(s) will be placed here
        - bottom : float
            The center of the bottommost node(s) will be placed here
        - top : float
            The center of the topmost node(s) will be placed here
        - layer_sizes : list of int
            List of layer sizes, including input and output dimensionality
    '''
    n_layers = len(layer_sizes)
    v_spacing = (top - bottom)/float(max(layer_sizes))
    h_spacing = (right - left)/float(len(layer_sizes) - 1)
    normed_coef = np.array([(c / np.max(np.abs(c)) + 1) /2 for c in coefs_])


    # Input-Arrows
    layer_top_0 = v_spacing*(layer_sizes[0] - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
    for m in range(layer_sizes[0]):
        plt.arrow(left-0.15, layer_top_0 - m*v_spacing, 0.12, 0,  lw =0.05, head_width=0.01, head_length=0.02)
    
    # Nodes
    for n, layer_size in enumerate(layer_sizes):
        layer_top = v_spacing*(layer_size - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
        for m in range(layer_size):
            circle = plt.Circle((n*h_spacing + left, layer_top - m*v_spacing), v_spacing/8.,
                                color='w', ec='k', zorder=4)
            if n == 0:
                plt.text(left-0.125, layer_top - m*v_spacing, r'$X_{'+str(m+1)+'}$', fontsize=15)
            elif (n_layers == 3) & (n == 1):
                plt.text(n*h_spacing + left+0.00, layer_top - m*v_spacing+ (v_spacing/8.+0.01*v_spacing), r'$H_{'+str(m+1)+'}$', fontsize=15)
            elif n == n_layers -1:
                plt.text(n*h_spacing + left+0.10, layer_top - m*v_spacing, r'$y_{'+str(m+1)+'}$', fontsize=15)
            ax.add_artist(circle)

    # Edges between nodes
    for n, (layer_size_a, layer_size_b) in enumerate(zip(layer_sizes[:-1], layer_sizes[1:])):
        layer_top_a = v_spacing*(layer_size_a - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
        layer_top_b = v_spacing*(layer_size_b - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
        for m in range(layer_size_a):
            for o in range(layer_size_b):
                line = plt.Line2D([n*h_spacing + left, (n + 1)*h_spacing + left],
                                  [layer_top_a - m*v_spacing, layer_top_b - o*v_spacing], c=cmap(normed_coef[n][m, o]))
                ax.add_artist(line)
                xm = (n*h_spacing + left)
                xo = ((n + 1)*h_spacing + left)
                ym = (layer_top_a - m*v_spacing)
                yo = (layer_top_b - o*v_spacing)
                rot_mo_rad = np.arctan((yo-ym)/(xo-xm))
                rot_mo_deg = rot_mo_rad*180./np.pi
                xm1 = xm + (v_spacing/8.+0.05)*np.cos(rot_mo_rad)
                if n == 0:
                    if yo > ym:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.12)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                    else:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.05)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                else:
                    if yo > ym:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.12)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                    else:
                        ym1 = ym + (v_spacing/8.+0.04)*np.sin(rot_mo_rad)
                plt.text( xm1, ym1,\
                         str(round(coefs_[n][m, o],4)),\
                         rotation = rot_mo_deg, \
                         fontsize = 10)
               
    # Output-Arrows
    layer_top_0 = v_spacing*(layer_sizes[-1] - 1)/2. + (top + bottom)/2.
    for m in range(layer_sizes[-1]):
        plt.arrow(right+0.011, layer_top_0 - m*v_spacing, 0.16*h_spacing, 0,  lw =0.05, head_width=0.01, head_length=0.02)
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.axis('off')

layer_sizes = [7] + [10] + [7]
# layer_sizes = nodes
draw_neural_net(ax, .1, .9, .1, .9, layer_sizes, coefs_)
# fig.savefig('nn_digaram.png')
```

[image]